# How count rows for each rows in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get rows from `table1:`

```
SELECT table1.id,  COUNT(commentTable1.id) AS CNT3,  COUNT(photoTable1.id) AS CNT2, COUNT(fileTable1.id)  AS CNT3 FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN commentTable1 ON...
LEFT JOIN photoTable1 ON...
LEFT JOIN fileTable1 ON ...
```

How right use `GROUP BY` for each `COUNT`? Now I get wrong number of `CNT3`

Comment: GROUP BY `table1.id`...I guess

Comment: Yes, now is same groupping by primary key of table `table1`. It gives me wrong number

Comment: Please, post your data (or sqlfiddle) and the desired result.

Comment: is a typo? - you have two same aliases `CNT3`

Comment: Give further information.

Comment: Sorry here IS not `CNT3` `CNT1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot group by a count, so I assume you are grouping by `table1.id`

```
SELECT table1.id,  COUNT(commentTable1.id) AS CNT3,  COUNT(photoTable1.id) AS CNT2, COUNT(fileTable1.id)  AS CNT3 FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN commentTable1 ON...
LEFT JOIN photoTable1 ON...
LEFT JOIN fileTable1 ON ...
GROUP BY table1.id
```